# Спарсить сообщение между двумя сплиттерами

Tags: c++, строки

Имеются сообщения вида:

```
Param0 = 0, Param1 = 2, Vec4;int;
```

Нужно спарсить так, чтобы на выходе получить значение Param1, тоесть 2, сейчас паршу так:

```
std::string string_parse( std::string message , char start , char end )
{
    std::string temp;
    std::stringstream strstream( message );

    if(!std::getline( strstream , temp , start ) || !std::getline( strstream , temp , end ) )
        return "";

    return temp;
}
```

Проблема в том что char принимает только 1 символ, а нужно парсить сразу по строчке, тоесть

```
std::string msg = "Param0 = 0, Param1 = 2, Vec4;int;";
std::string param1 = string_parse(msg, "Param1 ="/*первый сплиттер*/, ", Vec4"/*второй*/);
// param1 должно получится "2"
```

Comment: Почему бы не использовать регулярные выражения?

Comment: совсем о них забыл, тоже можно как вариант